# how to add a folder to Places in caja?

Tags: debian, caja, mate-desktop

In caja it seems there is no way to add a folder to the Places menu. I tried caja help menu > F1 but didn't get anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

This is in caja 1.20.0

[image: Partial image of Places in caja]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your home folder, inside .config theres a file called user-dirs.dirs, just edit that file to your liking. Heres a copy of mine

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  I can't get a new folder just by adding a line to this file.

Answer (score 6):

Another method besides what @christian mentioned that does not require config file edit is to add the folder as a bookmark:

- Step into the folder you would like to add
- Bookmarks -> Add Bookmark

After you added a folder to the bookmarks, you will be able to drag-and-drop additional folders by dropping them on the **Bookmark** label.

Answer (score 0):

yep!

accidentally moved my Videos than back again
it was gone from the list

got my Videos folder back in the list - yeah!

but...

caja does not recognize Templates directory

learned something new about Linux & caja

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/426083)